# Can I make ProgressMonitor dialog modal?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jprogressbar, concurrency

is there a way to make the dialog from **ProgressMonitor** modal?

**EDIT:**

The ProgressMonitor class in JAVA API will bring a dialog which is on the top but not Modal. User still has access to the background GUI. I am looking for a Modal dialog to show the progress and also allow user to stop the task in the middle.

Comment: my Custom ProgressThreadMonitor is Modal, can you be more concrete

Comment: where is your ProgressThreadMonitor?

Comment: my ProgressThreadMonitor is based on http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html and  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html, then you can create by own JDialog#setModal(true); or JDialog#setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL); and put there your JProgressBar, be sure that required based on these rules http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in [*How to Use Progress Monitors*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html#monitors), a number of factors should be considered when [*Deciding Whether to Use a Progress Bar or a Progress Monitor*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html#deciding). As an implementation detail, [`ProgressMonitor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html) is modeless because "the Solaris [implementation](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/swing/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.java.htm) doesn't support `Dialog.setModal` yet." As a practical matter, a modal `ProgressMonitor` is just a `JOptionPane` with a `JProgressBar`, but users may appreciate an effort to avoid such modal behavior.